# vue display and hide object property design

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I didn't know how to properly ask this question, so first sorry about the bad title.

Basically, to explain the problem I use the context of a web application that I am building with vueJS.

In this application I have a simple table that is rendered with data that comes from the server, basically I get an array of objects, and each object has some properties, the scope of the properties is not important.

Now I want to display some data in a table, and if some of the properties don't come from the server, I want to hide the property on the table, but keep the structure of the table, the missing property should have a empty space on the table.

**I did it this way:**

```
<div :style="{'visibility': computedValue}"></div>
```

This compute value basically is a computed property that returns the 'hidden' or 'show' for the visibility property.

But this brings some issues; on the computed property I am returning data based on the property object, for example:

`company.createdAt` can be undefined and I still have a error if I use visibility with `:style`.

I come from an angular environment where `v-if` and `v-show` were a little different,  I know that v-if takes the element out from the DOM and v-show keeps it, but in vue if I do the above example with v-show it still works as v-if in the way that the rendered data works like the data was removed from the DOM.

I just wanted the empty space like it still is there.

Any help or explanations on this?

Comment: Why not conditionally render a css class on the element that goes like `.hidden { visibility: hidden; }`?

Comment: that is not the problem, i can do it of course but the element is still there, if the element doesn't show up it will stil be on the html and if object.property is undefinedi i still get the error

Comment: I don't understand your problem.

Comment: `v-show` will toggle `display:none` to the element, `display:none` will   both hide and remove an element from the document layout. for above your use case, probably this way meet your requirements: `<div :style="{'visibility': company && company.createdAt ? 'visible' : 'hidden'}"></div>`

Comment: Your question is indeed confusing. In fact, I don't even know what the question is. What exactly are you asking?

Comment: with vuejs v-show and v-if have the same effect on the rendering display, even if one of them remove the element from the dom, that is my problem

Answer (score 6):

You can add your own `v-visible` using a vue directive. Simple add this:

```
Vue.directive('visible', (el, bind) => {
    el.style.visibility=(!!bind.value) ? 'visible' : 'hidden';});
```

Then use it like you would `v-show`

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to hide the element but preserve the space, right? [vue-visible](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-visible) is a simple npm package that I used recently to do that; the benefit is when you include it, you can very easily and semantically use it like this: `v-visible="value"`, just like v-show or v-if, with `value` being true/false.

Comment: exactly, why vuejs didn't implement v-show to preserve space can't get it? why use another dependency?

Answer (score 0):

npm install @ventralnet/v-hide^1.0.0

https://github.com/ventralnet/v-hide

That adds a new directive (v-hide="...") to vue2/vue3 that will make use of visibility: hidden so dom space is maintained